# What's wrong with the hive sql statement?

Tags: hive, hiveql

user_id:821044249473 return in the result's set after excuting below hive sql

```
select distinct(t1.user_id) from b2c_d.A t1 inner join b2c_d.B t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id inner join b2cdc.C t3 on t1.user_id = t3.base_uid
where t1.active_rate > 0.9 and t1.micloud_usage > 0.9 and t1.user_level > 5 
 and t3.order_accessory_amount >100 and t3.order_accessory_amount < 3000 and t3.order_total_amount > 10000 and t3.order_total_amount < 50000
and t1.play_date > 10
and t1.user_id not in(
...
)
```

So, what's wrong? why user_id 821044249473 is contained in the result's set?

Thanks

Comment: **But** the order_total_amount of this user is 2199.0 in b2cdc.C, it should not be selected according the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific on what's the input and what you are looking in the O/P.
From just browsing over the SQL i think you will have use SEMI join since in HIVEQL you wont be able to use IN like MySQL.